# cannot change class variables while runtime swift

Tags: ios, class, swift, variables

That's an what I want to do. I want to change a class variable while the project is running and use that in player. For example, while the app is running when user plays a button the player will stop and change the URL and start again. How can I do it?

EDIT: Question changed to avoid forum pollution.

```
let pa = PlayerAv()

class PlayerAv
{
    var audioLink = ""
    var player: AVPlayer
    init()
    {
        player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: self.audioLink))
    }
}

@IBAction func changeToSabiha() {
    pa.player.pause()
    PlayerAv().audioLink = "http://someurl.com/bcd.pls"
    println("\(pa.audioLink)")
    pa.player.play()
}
```

//The whole code

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
import GoogleMobileAds


class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var statLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ataturkButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sabihaButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var esenbogaButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var weatherButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!

    var googleBannerView: GADBannerView!




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        googleBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
        googleBannerView.adUnitID = "adunitIDXXXX"
        googleBannerView.rootViewController = self
        var request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
        googleBannerView.loadRequest(request)

        googleBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.bounds.height - googleBannerView.frame.size.height, googleBannerView.frame.size.width, googleBannerView.frame.size.height)
        self.view.addSubview(googleBannerView!)



        //setTitle commands start
        statusLabel.text = "Status: Not Playing"
        playButton.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        weatherButton.setTitle("Show Weather", forState: .Normal)
        ataturkButton.setTitle("Ataturk - LTBA", forState: .Normal)
        sabihaButton.setTitle("Sabiha Gökçen - LTFJ", forState: .Normal)
        esenbogaButton.setTitle("Esenboğa - LTAC", forState: .Normal)
        //setTitle commands end





        switch Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {
        case false :
            println("Internet connection FAILED")
            var alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
        default:
            println("Internet connection OK")


        }


    }//viewDidLoad() end

    let pa = PlayerAv().audioLink

    class PlayerAv
    {
        var audioLink:String = ""
        var player: AVPlayer
        init()
        {
            player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: self.audioLink))
        }
    }


    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        var currentValue = Float(sender.value)
        println(currentValue)
        PlayerAv().player.volume = currentValue
    }


    @IBAction func getWeatherWindow(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "somewebpage.com")!)
        println("Directed to weather page")
    }





    //Tower change statements start

    @IBAction func changeToAtaturk() {
        PlayerAv().player.pause()
        pa == "http://someurl.com/def.pls"
        println("\(pa)--a")
        PlayerAv().player.play()
    }



    @IBAction func changeToEsenboga() {
        PlayerAv().player.pause()
        PlayerAv().audioLink = "http://someurl.com/bcd.pls"
        println("\(pa)--a")
        PlayerAv().player.play()
    }

    @IBAction func changeToSabiha() {
        PlayerAv().player.pause()
        pa == "http://someurl.com/abc.pls"
        println("\(pa)--a")
        PlayerAv().player.play()
    }


    //Tower change statements end




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        toggle()
    }


    func toggle() {
        if playButton.titleLabel?.text == "Play" {
            playRadio()
            println("Playing")
            statusLabel.text = "Status: Playing"
        } else {
            pauseRadio()
            println("Paused")
            statusLabel.text = "Status: Paused"
        }
    }

    func playRadio() {
        PlayerAv().player.play()
        playButton.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    }

    func pauseRadio() {
        PlayerAv().player.pause()
        playButton.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent) {
        if event.type == UIEventType.RemoteControl {
            if event.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPlay {
                println("received remote play")
                playRadio()
            } else if event.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPause {
                println("received remote pause")
                pauseRadio()
            } else if event.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlTogglePlayPause {
                println("received toggle")
                toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PlayerAv().audioLink, Here it will create another instance and it is different from instance pa. Please provide more input.

Comment: Can you please give more details about your comment?

Comment: I solved the problem from the answer of Eric D. But let me explain it. I used to want to change the PlayerAv().audioLink's value with buttons while the app is running. Before I couldn't, now I can. Thank you for your attension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, is not good, because you create a player with an invalid URL:

```
// NOT GOOD
class PlayerAv {
    var audioLink: String = ""
    var player: AVPlayer
    init()
    {
        player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: self.audioLink))
    }
}
let myPlayer = PlayerAv()
```

It's better to initialize the player once you know what URL you want to use:

```
// GOOD
class PlayerAv {
    var audioLink: String?
    var player: AVPlayer
    init(link: String) {
        self.audioLink = link
        self.player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: link))
    }
}
```

Also, make it a `var` so we can change the content later:

```
var myPlayer = PlayerAv(link: "http://yourFirstURLhere")
```

**Now, this `myPlayer` object is your player**.

If you want to use it:

```
myPlayer.player.play()
myPlayer.player.pause()
myPlayer.player.volume = 2
```

Now what needs to happen if you want a player with a new link?

*That's when you create a new one*, with the new link, but you want to assign this new player *to the same instance variable*, so:

```
myPlayer = PlayerAv(link: "http://yourNewURLhere")
myPlayer.player.play()
```

*Note that we just assigned a new created player object to the existing `myPlayer` variable.*

If you want to print the current link:

```
println(myPlayer.audiolink!)
```

Inside the `myPlayer` object are the player itself (`player`) and the link (`audioLink`).

*Note: these were examples based on your code. But you should have a look at something like [this](http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/swift-avfoundation/#audiofile) for interesting working examples of using AVPlayer.*